# Why does sk_buff have a ip header pointer (ipiphdr) in the h union and a regular ip header pointer (iphdr) in the nh union?

Tags: c, sockets, networking, linux-kernel

This is more a curiosity question. I have been looking through the linux network kernal and noticed that sk_buff had two pointers to a ipv4 header in separate unions. What is the reasoning behind this? is there an event where a packet could have more than one ip header?

**EDIT**
Here is a link to where I saw it. I have seen this else where as well. 
[sk_buff](http://www.cse.scu.edu/~dclark/am_256_graph_theory/linux_2_6_stack/structsk__buff.html)

```
00202         union {
00203                 struct tcphdr   *th;
00204                 struct udphdr   *uh;
00205                 struct icmphdr  *icmph;
00206                 struct igmphdr  *igmph;
00207                 struct iphdr    *ipiph;
00208                 struct ipv6hdr  *ipv6h;
00209                 unsigned char   *raw;
00210         } h;
00211 
00212         union {
00213                 struct iphdr    *iph;
00214                 struct ipv6hdr  *ipv6h;
00215                 struct arphdr   *arph;
00216                 unsigned char   *raw;
00217         } nh;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: unix.SE would probably be a better place for this.

Comment: And providing a or snippet of (and link to), the code you're talking about would save people having to go hunting for it.

Comment: I don't see `ipiphdr` or `iphdr` in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/skbuff.h

Comment: @Barmar Ok maybe I'm looking at a non linux sk_buff. Because the sk_buff site you linked only has indexes to the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`h` is the header for the transport layer.  `nh` is the header for the network layer.

But in raw sockets, there's no transport protocol, so the header is the network layer header.

Comment: That seems to be a good reason. Thanks for sating my curiosity.